# How to make Alert Dialog disappear after 30 seconds in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

So I am using an Alert Dialog in my project which should either be closed if the user clicks 'Ok' or 'Cancel' else it should disappear on its own after 30 seconds if the user gives no response. I was thinking of using `setState` and `Duration` or something like that but can't exactly figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Future.delayed` to have a delayed action:

```
// dialog builder
showDialog(context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
  bool manuallyClosed = false;
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30)).then((_) {
    if (!manuallyClosed) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop());
    }
  });

  // Build the dialog window
  // Set manuallyClosed to true on the OK or Cancel button tap
});
```

Comment: A little correction .then() cant take a null argument function so I used then((_){})

Comment: @HarshilChaudhary Coding from memory is fun.